# orderby is not giving correct results in spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset of around 60 columns and 3000 rows.
I am using orderby for sorting rows in dataset and writing in a file
But its not giving correct results as excpeted.

```
dataset.orderBy(new Column(col_name).desc())
                .coalesce(4)
                .write()
                .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .option("delimiter", ",")
                .option("header", "false")
                .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                .save("hdfs://" + filePath);
```

Please let me know what I am missing here

Also I found below solution but don't think that is the correct solution

```
        Row[] rows = dataset.take(3000);

        for ( Row row : rows){
            // here i am writing in a file row by row
            System.out.println(row);
        }
```

Comment: What is your intent? `coalesce(4)` will give 4 files . Do you want the ordering within each file only? Or you want a single file with proper ordering?

Comment: if coalesce not used it creates 200 files thats why i used coalesce(4) to create only 4 files at the end. after this i am writing 4 files into one final file. like below ```         FSDataInputStream inputStream;
        FileStatus[] partFiles = hdfs.globStatus(new Path(reportDatePath + "/part*"));
        for (FileStatus fileStatus : partFiles) {
            inputStream = hdfs.open(fileStatus.getPath());
            IOUtils.copyBytes(inputStream, reportFileOs, hadoopConf, false);
            IOUtils.closeStream(inputStream);
        }```

Comment: but your final single file won't have order guarantee.

Comment: yes.. thats what happening:( so should i use coalesce(1) here?  isn't it cause issue when  data is 3 4 time larger than size i mentioned in question

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that `coalesce` will merge your existing partitions in an unsorted way (and no, `coalesce` will not cause a shuffle).

If you want 4 files and sorting within the files, you need to change `spark.sql.suffle.partitions` before the `orderBy`, this will cause your shuffle to have 4 partitions.

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=4")

dataset.orderBy(new Column(col_name).desc())
            .write()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("delimiter", ",")
            .option("header", "false")
            .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
            .save("hdfs://" + filePath);
```

if you only care about the sorting within the files, you could also use `sortWithinPartitions(new Column(col_name).desc())`

Answer (score 2):

because your `.coalesce(4)` suffle your dataframe order

coalesce first then  sort .

```
dataset
.coalesce(4)
.orderBy(new Column(col_name).desc())                
.write()
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("delimiter", ",")
.option("header", "false")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.save("hdfs://" + filePath);
```

you also should set `spark.sql.suffle.partitions` to 4 in your spark context because order by also provoque suffle.

Comment: this does not make any sense. `orderBy` will shuffle again to 200 (default) partitions

Comment: After your edit  `coalesce(4)` doesn't add any value. it's redundant

Answer (score 0):

As per your clarification in the comments, you need your `ordered` output to be contained in a single file.

With only spark, that's possible only with `spark.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1")` followed by `orderBy` and write. But the drawback is it `won't scale` for big data as it will not be parallelized.

A work around is :

- Make your spark do the `orderBy` with maximum parallelized work, (i.e. don't `coalesce` or  `"set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1"`) and have `n` number of files.
- Add some extra logical handling in your file merging code
- List All files, fetch the value of `col_name` and maintain a map of `[(col_name value), filepath]`
- Sort the map by key (value of `col_name`)
- Then perform your merge

This will maintain your ordering.

The idea is, the merging part will be mostly single threaded, at least do the sorting in a distributed way :)